# Openstack: How do I extend the nova host-describe command?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I would like to extend the nova command host-describe by adding more columns with data from the database, however I fail to see how the initial request from shell.py (by the method "do_host_describe") travels to the database. I have searched for related documentation and also used PDB to follow along in the code. PDB showed me how the requests is built layer for layer, but I am unable to figure out where it is sent, and who catches it (whom also eventually send the correct data back). My investigations suggest the nova-api service should be involved, and that the path should be

Command line -> nova-api service -> Database (and then back again)

I am grateful for any pointers since I am at a loss on how to continue on my own!

In short: How does the request from a "nova host-describe" command reach the database? Where would I need to modify the code to allow the displayed table to include more data/columns?

I am currently using the Icehouse release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for the command line client, we can see in `novaclient/v2/shell.py` that the `host-describe` command is simply displaying information returned by `cs.hosts.get(...)`, where `cs` is the result of calling `novaclient.client.Client`.

The `get` method results in a call to the `/os-host/` REST endpoint, which you can see by running `nova` with `--debug`:

```
DEBUG (session:195) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://openstack.local:8774/v2/5b358dbdb37841c8b119834c94a0b943/os-hosts/openstack.local -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}766b819cdf615d221818c388c666d54415af8d16"
INFO (connectionpool:203) Starting new HTTP connection (1): openstack.local
DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/5b358dbdb37841c8b119834c94a0b943/os-hosts/openstack.local HTTP/1.1" 200 477
DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 14:20:50 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 477 x-compute-request-id: req-9d421331-a4cd-4db4-833d-967224dd24db 
RESP BODY: {"host": [{"resource": {"project": "(total)", "memory_mb": 7794, "host": "openstack.local", "cpu": 1, "disk_gb": 78}}, {"resource": {"project": "(used_now)", "memory_mb": 1536, "host": "openstack.local", "cpu": 1, "disk_gb": 10}}, {"resource": {"project": "(used_max)", "memory_mb": 1024, "host": "openstack.local", "cpu": 1, "disk_gb": 10}}, {"resource": {"project": "f4e7e158cb154de5ab503bd7096b8981", "memory_mb": 1024, "host": "openstack.local", "cpu": 1, "disk_gb": 10}}]}

+-----------------+----------------------------------+-----+-----------+---------+
| HOST            | PROJECT                          | cpu | memory_mb | disk_gb |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+-----+-----------+---------+
| openstack.local | (total)                          | 1   | 7794      | 78      |
| openstack.local | (used_now)                       | 1   | 1536      | 10      |
| openstack.local | (used_max)                       | 1   | 1024      | 10      |
| openstack.local | f4e7e158cb154de5ab503bd7096b8981 | 1   | 1024      | 10      |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Looking at the source for `nova`, we can see that for the compute API `v2`, the `os-hosts` extension is provided by `nova/api/openstack/compute/contrib/hosts.py`.  It looks as if the `show` method generates the data for `host-describe`, so this is probably where you would make your changes.

Database access in openstack is handled via [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).  In general, this means that accessing database fields is done by accessing attributes on Python objects.  The existing code should provide reasonable examples.